# Need a COUNT from another table added into a select

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to get user results from one table (tbl_b) and the count of ID's of another table (tbl_a).

```
tbl_b:

ID       NAME       LAST_NAME         UNTIL_DATE
================================================
1        Sharon     Alexander         2016-04-01
2        David      Lynn              2014-04-01
3        Jason      Rominsky          2015-04-01


tbl_a:

ID      
==
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

And the (obviously erroneous) query:

```
SELECT tbl_b.ID, tbl_b.NAME, tbl_b.LAST_NAME, COUNT(tbl_a.ID) as TOTAL
FROM tbl_a, tbl_b
WHERE tbl_b.UNTIL_DATE>=NOW()
```

I need to select a list of people from tbl_b alongside with a total of logins from tbl_a (each login has an ID).
What happens is that if tbl_b is empty or UNTIL_DATE is less than `NOW()`, the result of TOTAL would equal 0, which is wrong. (the result must be a positive number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a correlated sub-query to count:

```
SELECT tbl_b.ID, tbl_b.NAME, tbl_b.LAST_NAME,
       (select COUNT(*) from tbl_a where tbl_a.id = tbl_b.id) as TOTAL
FROM tbl_b
WHERE tbl_b.UNTIL_DATE >= NOW()
```

Or do a left outer join with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT tbl_b.ID, tbl_b.NAME, tbl_b.LAST_NAME, COUNT(tbl_a.ID) as TOTAL
FROM tbl_b LEFT JOIN tbl_a ON tbl_a.id = tbl_b.id
WHERE tbl_b.UNTIL_DATE >= NOW()
GROUP BY tbl_b.ID, tbl_b.NAME, tbl_b.LAST_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I use MSSQL

```
SELECT tbl_b.ID, tbl_b.NAME, tbl_b.LAST_NAME, ISNULL(Logins.TOTAL_LOGINS, 0) as TOTAL
FROM tbl_b
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ID, COUNT(*)  as TOTAL_LOGINS FROM tbl_a GROUP BY ID) as Logins
ON tbl_b.ID = Logins.ID WHERE tbl_b.UNTIL_DATE >= NOW ()
```